# XML data types specification

Tags: java, xml

While there is plenty of documentation about XML document structure, there are very few links to how non textual data (eg. integer and decimal numbers, boolean values) should be managed. 
Is there a consolidated standard? Could tell me a good starting point?
**POST SCRIPT**
I add an example because the question is actually too generic.

I've defined a document structure:

```
<rectangle>
  <width>12.45</width>
  <height>23.34</heigth>
  <rounded_corners>true</rounded_corners>
</rectangle>
```

Since I'm using DOM, the API is oriented to textual data. Say `doc` is an instance of `Document`. `doc.createTextNode("takes a string")`. That is: API doesn't force towards a particular rapresentation. 
So two question arise:
1) saving bolean true as 'true' instead of uhm, 1/0 is a standard?
2) i have to define simple methods that write and parse from and to this string representations. Example. I may use java wrappers to do this conversion:

```
Float f = 23.34;
doc.createTextNode(f.toString());
```

but does it adhere to the xml standard for decimal numbers? If so, i can say that a non-java programs can read this data because the data representation is xml. 
**why not jaxb**
This is just an example, my xml is made up of a big tree of data and i need to write and read just a little part of it, so JAXB seems not to fit very well. Binding architecture tends to establish a tight copuling between xml structure and class structure. Good implementations like moxy let you loosen this coupling, but there are cases in wich the two structures simply don't match. In those cases, the DTO used to adapt them would be more work than using DOM.

Comment: Have you looked into the XML Schema language standard which helps one define and constrain the structure of related XML's? I think I learned more about XML document structures by learning about this. Tutorials for it abound with a Google search; if you haven't done so, consider giving it a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can leverage the `javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter` class to convert simple Java types to a String that conforms to the XML Schema specification:

```
Float f = 23.34f;
doc.createTextNode(DatatypeConverter.printFloat(f));
```

Answer (score 2):

Of course, there are dozens of official standards related to core XML. Some of the important ones:

1. [XML schema 1.1 overview](http://www.w3.org/XML/Schema)
2. [XML schema 1.1 - datatypes ('XSD')](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema11-2/)
3. [XML schema 1.1 - structures](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema11-1/)
4. [Core XML overview](http://www.w3.org/XML/)
5. [XML 1.0](http://www.w3.org/TR/2008/REC-xml-20081126/)
6. [XML 1.1](http://www.w3.org/TR/2006/REC-xml11-20060816/)

Further specification like XPath, XQuery are available at [www.w3.org/standards/xml/](http://www.w3.org/standards/xml/). As you tagged this question with `java` you may be interested in [JAXB](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/index-140168.html) as well, which defines a standard approach for mapping XML to Java and vice versa.

Comment: i am just intrested in a comprehensive data - type NOT document structure specification. i've alredy defined the DOM structure, so my concern is now which format use to save an integer, a decimal value, a boolean etc. into an element.

Comment: So XML schema datatypes should tell you? Do you need a mapping from Java to XML? Have a look at http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema11-2/#built-in-primitive-datatypes

Comment: I think if you write the XML directly using DOM you must ask the XML provider which format he requires for e.g. floating point values. Is the target XML backed by a schema?

Comment: Consider this. Different companies that use different developement technologies have to agree on a configuration file based on xml. I have to propose the xml structure. I must leverage standards but at the same time i have to keep it simple.

Comment: +1 - I believe that the link to the XML Schema 1.1 Datatypes specification is the answer to this question.  @AgonstinoX, an XML Schema is how you specify the XML Structure so that different companies can interact.  I have added an answer that demonstrates how to convert Java datatypes to a valid XML representation:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7539040/xml-data-types-specification/7558060#7558060

Comment: @AgostinoX: If you need an exchange format between different companies, you should really go with XSD. Define the datamodel in XSD and everyone will be on the same page.